Creating multiple indices in ElasticSearch
A website exists for a collection of scientific literature databases, where users can search and be redirected to them. The dataset contains approximately 16,000 documents (in this case databases), each of which can be annotated with various metadata (like keywords, subject categories, authors etc.). However, more than 300 institutions also participate in this collection, with each institution being able to individually overwrite and extend the metadata of each dataset. This additional metadata added by the institutions is then only displayed in the institution-specific view of the website. If the user is not affiliated with an institution, the general metadata is displayed. The data is stored in a PostgreSQL database.
I considered creating a separate index in ElasticSearch via Logstash for each institution, which would contain both the global and institution-specific metadata combined. In addition, there would be a global index dedicated to general metadata only. Depending on which institution the user logs in to, the appropriate index would be searched.
Would this approach make sense, or could everything be thrown into one big index? I have already configured Logstash to query and index only the global data. If I wanted to create multiple indexes, would I need to call the Logstash configuration from a bash script, looping through the institutions and passing the institution ID each time?
Thank you very much in advance!

In my opinion 16k documents are relatively small. For instance i am using an index with 20 millions of documents. It gets really harder to manage the index if it keeps growing.
In your case you can use multiple pipelines.
In multiple pipelines, you should define the names of the pipelines in pipeline.yml in logstash. For example:
pipeline.yml
- pipeline.id: my-pipeline_1
  path.config: "/etc/path/to/institution-1.conf"
  pipeline.workers: 3
- pipeline.id: my-pipeline_2
  path.config: "/etc/path/to/institution-2.conf"
  queue.type: persisted

Then create a pipeline (.conf) file for every pipeline under config folder.
institution-1.conf
institution-2.conf
.
.
.

And for each pipeline you should define input, filter and output plugins in your .conf pipelines in order to ingest the data.
But you have 300 institutions so I am not sure if this fits because you need to create 300 pipelines and I do not know if they will grow in the future.
If the data are stabile and do not grow, you can create a one big index and define a field for example "institution: .." and ingest data accordingly. Then you can filter in your client code.

Thanks for the answer! I will first try to throw all the data into an index, the data should not grow too much. If filtering the data doesn't work well, I would create a separate pipeline for each institution. But both suggestions sound very applicable.
